# XSLT - Change value of element in xml based on some condition

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to modify the content of xml based on value of some elemnt in the input xml.

**Input XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Objects>
<Object class="Item" version="1.0" distName="A-1/B-1/Item-0">
 <p name="sDate">2013-02-11T00:00:00+02:00:00</p>
 <p name="present">1</p>
 <p name="stopD">2013-02-21T00:00:00+02:00:00</p>
 <p name="id">CPU</p>
</Object>
<Object class="Item" version="1.0" distName="A-1/B-1/Item-1">
 <p name="sDate">2013-02-11T00:00:00+02:00:00</p>
 <p name="present">1</p>
 <p name="stopD">2013-02-21T00:00:00+02:00:00</p>
 <p name="id">CPU</p>
</Object>
</Objects>
```

The XSL should change the value of an element based on its value.
For Eg:
In node **Item**, if the value of element **sDate** is **2013-02-11T00:00:00+02:00:00** , i need to make it empty like shown below.

**Output XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Objects>
<Object class="Item" version="1.0" distName="A-1/B-1/Item-0">
<p name="sDate"></p>
<p name="present">1</p>
<p name="stopD">2013-02-21T00:00:00+02:00:00</p>
<p name="id">CPU</p>
</Object>
<Object class="Item" version="1.0" distName="A-1/B-1/Item-1">
<p name="sDate"></p>
<p name="present">1</p>
<p name="stopD">2013-02-21T00:00:00+02:00:00</p>
<p name="id">CPU</p>
</Object>
</Objects>
```

I tried some xsl but couldnt get the thing working.. Any leads?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not quite clear. The following stylesheet will do exactly what you ask for - but I am not sure it provides a general example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p[@name='sDate'][.='2013-02-11T00:00:00+02:00:00']">
    <p name="sDate"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Note**:

> In node **Item**, if the value of element **sDate** is
>   2013-02-11T00:00:00+02:00:00

There is no `Item` node in your XML, nor a `sDate` element.